# Do I need a shader for Phong?

Tags: three.js, shader

do I need to write a shader for phong,
Well I know I do but, when using THREE.js do i need one?

I have been reading this book (http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781849699792.do) it explains how to write a phong shader.

I thought I would try it out, but then found this:  http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/MeshPhongMaterial

Are there any differences between the two? How about if I had a large detailed model, as opposed to a sphere?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to write a phone shader. The Phong material provided by three.js is an implementation of the [Blinn–Phong shading model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinn%E2%80%93Phong_shading_model), and you can use it for any of your models.

Implementing your own would not result in any difference, but it likely would be great to further your understanding.

Comment: No, `MeshPhongMaterial` implements the Blinn-Phong illumination model.